# QGIS network analysis, points on graph cannot be reached

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, network, network-analysis, qgis-network-analysis

Using QGIS 2.18.14, I try something around with `qgis.networkanalysis` module as described here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html

```
director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector(network, -1, '', '', '', 3)
properter = QgsDistanceArcProperter()
director.addProperter(properter)
crs = network.crs()
builder = QgsGraphBuilder(crs)

tiedPoints = director.makeGraph(builder, [start_geom] + target_list)
# target_list is a list of QgsPoints()
# start_point is a QgsPoint()
graph = builder.graph()
```

Everything seems to work so far, tied point are generated correctly, but when I try to find paths from `start_point` to the targets by

```
(tree, cost) = QgsGraphAnalyzer.dijkstra(graph, idSource, 0)
```

some of the `tied_points` cannot be reached in the graph (i.e. `tree[id_target] =-1` for certain point).

My first thought was that there is something wrong with my vector layer but it seems topologically correct (no gaps or duplicate consecutive point e.g.), no matter if LineStrings or MultiLineStrings.

Since I thought that each tied point should be reachable in the graph, what can be the reason for the 'non-reachability' of some points on such? Could this be a problem of LineString directions in the network layer?

Answer (score 2):

Is your road network fully noded? I.e. has separate lines for every intersection? That's a pre-requisite for the network analysis module.

Comment: I think so. The developer cookbook says: "Two lines that have a common node become connected to each other." so a T-shaped situation has a common node in the triple point, but not common end nodes. So do I have to break such situations in a way that the vector dataset have solely end nodes in common? And does it matter if its type is Lines or Polylines?

Comment: A "T" intersection must have a node on the straight segment too (eg at the middle of the top line of the "T"). There's no requirement for having either lines or (multi)polylines - either will work.